# Invalid form doesn't get normalized when using FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, normalization, fosrestbundle

Using FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializerBundle I cannot get my invalid forms to get wrapped in an exception via `\FOS\RestBundle\Serializer\Normalizer\FormErrorHandler`, like described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html#forms-and-views).

Instead of the HTTP response to contain the JSON object like described in the aforementioned URL (e.g. with `code`, `message` and `errors` keys), I see the serialized JSON representation of the Form object (I have the JMSSerializerBundle registered). The HTTP status does get set to 400. The JSON of the response:

```
{
  "children": {
    "title": {},
    "sourceAddress": {
      "errors": [
        "This value should not be blank."
      ]
    },
    "payload": {}
  }
}
```

Related config and code:

config.yml:

```
fos_rest:
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/, fallback_format: json }
    exception:
        enabled: true
```

Controller action:

```
public function postCampaignsAction(Request $request)
{
    $campaign = new Campaign();

    $form = $this->createForm(CampaignType::class, $campaign);
    $form->submit($request->request->all());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($campaign);
        $em->flush();

        return View::createRouteRedirect('get_campaign', [
            'campaign' => $campaign->getId(),
        ]);
    }

    return $form;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! :)

**EDIT:** I've managed to get the desired result by adding this to `parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
        jms_serializer.form_error_handler.class: FOS\RestBundle\Serializer\Normalizer\FormErrorHandler
```

I don't understand why this is necessary though, because `FOSRestBundle/Resources/config/serializer.xml` already contains:

```
    <parameters>
        <!-- Override the default jms FormErrorHandler -->
        <parameter key="jms_serializer.form_error_handler.class">FOS\RestBundle\Serializer\Normalizer\FormErrorHandler</parameter>
    </parameters>
```

Could this be a bug in FOSRestBundle?

Answer (score 1):

Found out what I did wrong: I put `FOSRestBundle` before `JMSSerializerBundle` in the array of bundles to register.

The order in which `JMSSerializerBundle` and `FOSRestBundle` are registered in `app/AppKernel.php` matters. If `FOSRestBundle` is ***before*** `JMSSerializerBundle` in the array returned in `\AppKernel::registerBundles`, the parameter override of `jms_serializer.form_error_handler.class` in the `Resources/config/serializer.xml` file of `FOSRestBundle` has no effect.